# Cookie unset on response.redirect

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am trying to create a login page with the ability to persist user login info (User ID/User Name) in cookies (although a session variable is used for immediate storage for the site). I am using the code below:

```
            Session("UserID") = USERS.GetUserID(Request.Form("UserName"))
            Session("FullName") = USERS.GetUserFullName(Session("UserID"))
            If Request.Form("RememberMe") = "True" Then
                Response.Cookies("UserID").Value = Session("UserID").ToString
                Response.Cookies("UserID").Expires = Now.AddDays(30)
                Response.Cookies("FullName").Value = Session("FullName").ToString
                Response.Cookies("FullName").Expires = Now.AddDays(30)
            End If
            Response.Redirect("~/VetPortal/Default.aspx")
```

I can track this step by step using Visual Studio and everything works just fine. The session variables are set, and the cookies are created properly. The problem is that when the redirect page is loaded, the cookies no longer are present. Am I missing something in setting the cookies that are preventing them from being retained? As I understand it, they should be retained until the expiration (today + 30 days).

Comment: Strange! You can see the cookies in your browser, and after the redirect they're gone?

Comment: Yeah... that is what I thought too. I wasn't sure if I am doing something/lacking something that is causing the browser to clear them out? I know that cookies are enabled in the browser and work just fine when they are not created by me...

Comment: How do you retrieve cookies in `~/VetPortal/Default.aspx`?

Comment: Try ether to `Response.Flush` before the redirect to force the cookie to saved, or redirect with false on second parameter. `Response.Redirect("~/VetPortal/Default.aspx", false)`